# How to limit EditText to input only float values in Java?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have found answers to limit it to Integer/float in xml, I want to do it programmatically. 
I can set `setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER)` for integer values, but what for float values?

I want them in `xxxx.xxx` format.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

in the xml file and

```
InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL
```

in the java source file.

**TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL** is a flag of **TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER** and allows decimal inputs.

For more information see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html)

In another way you can test the input value using

```
if(editText.getText().toString().contains("."))
     //Its a float value
else
     //Not a float value
```

Comment: Thanks, mate. FLAG_DECIMAL is allowing float inputs but also Character input, I want  only float and not text values. Now what?

Comment: @AyushGoyal in my case it is working fine. I have set this in xml structure. But it should work on both way. Please check once again.

Comment: @AyushGoyal Use setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL)

Answer (score 2):

Well simply use

> editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER|InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL)

only if you want to do it programmatically.